# constraints in prepareForInterfaceBuilder?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, ibdesignable

I'm no great fan of `@IBDesignable`, but in playing around with it I find that if you add a subview in `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`, the subview is added but constraints that you apply to it are not obeyed.

Is this a known limitation of `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`? That would make sense; I imagine that this method should be confined to doing things like giving a label some dummy text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure when adding a subview in `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` that you set its `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property to `false` if you want to use constraints on it and have it show up properly in Interface Builder. Such as:

```
@IBDesignable class View: UIView {
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()

        let subview = UIView()

        // Make sure to set this to false!
        subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // Just setting the background color so it can be seen in IB.
        subview.backgroundColor = .blue

        // Must add it as a subview before activating any constraints.
        addSubview(subview)

        // Adding some example constraints with some padding to make sure they're behaving properly.
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
            [subview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 20),
             subview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
             subview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
             subview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -20)]
        )
    }
}
```

This is an easy mistake to make because Xcode (10.3 as of writing this answer) does not give you any feedback about what's happening with the layout engine during `IBDesignable` rendering (no console log messages, no errors in Interface Builder, and nothing in the Report Navigator).